# How to jump over a specific number in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Didn't know how to call my Thread.

```
public NaturalNumberTuple(int[] numbers) {
    int [] thisTuple = new int[numbers.length];
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
        if(numbers[j] > 0){
            thisTuple[j] = numbers[j];
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] newTuple = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < newTuple.length; i++){
        int k = i;
        while(thisTuple[k] <= 0){
            k++;
        } 
        newTuple[i] = thisTuple[k];
    }
    this.tuple = newTuple;
}
```

This is my code snippet to create a new NaturalNumberTuple.

So this is the Array I want to use: int[] tT2 = {1,2,4,-4,5,4,4};
I only want to use natural numbers greater than 0 and my problem isn't to cut out the negative number but it is that my console is giving me this: Tuple(Numbers:1,2,4,5,5,4).
The problem is if I jump over that value which is negative with my while loop to get the higher (k) I will have to pass the same (k) in my for loop which I don't want to because I already got it in my Array. I hope you understand my problem. 
Sorry for the bad english..

Edit: Can't use any methods from java itself like System.arrayCopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the first loop. Fixing it makes the second loop much simpler :

```
public NaturalNumberTuple(int[] numbers) {
    int [] thisTuple = new int[numbers.length];
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
        if(numbers[j] > 0){
            thisTuple[count] = numbers[j]; // changed thisTuple[j] to thisTuple[count]
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] newTuple = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < newTuple.length; i++) {
        newTuple[i] = thisTuple[i];
    }
    this.tuple = newTuple;
}
```

Of course, the second loop can be replaced with a call to `System.arrayCopy`.

Comment: I can't use such methods, maybe I should add it to my question sorry

Comment: @NhatNienne My answer still works without using System.arrayCopy.

Comment: Edit: this is what it will give me: Tuple(Numbers:1,2,4,0,-4,5).
There is still something wrong :( So I still will get negative numbers

Comment: @NhatNienne Sorry. I got the indices mixed up. Should be `thisTuple[count] = numbers[j]`. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your while loop to an if that simply restarts the for loop. Say from this:

```
while(thisTuple[k] <= 0){
    k++;
}
```

To something like this:

```
if (thisTuple[k] <= 0)
    continue;
```

This stops you from adding the same number twice when you encounter a negative or zero number.

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve you issue. The code is checked in the following link [Tuple Exampple](http://ideone.com/79B1RZ)

```
    int [] thisTuple = new int[numbers.length];
    int count = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++){
        if(numbers[j] > 0){
            thisTuple[count] = numbers[j]; //Change to thisTuple[count]
            count++;
        }
    }
    int[] newTuple = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        newTuple[i] = thisTuple[i];
    }
```